# Is it possible to add music player or video player in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

How can I add music or video player in my application in Visual Studio 2010? It is possible right? But how can I do that?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Write one as a `UserControl`?

Comment: What kind of application do you mean? web application of winforms application?

Comment: What I mean is winform application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links for you to look at

http://www.csharphelp.com/archives4/archive680.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PoormansIPod01172007144720PM/PoormansIPod.aspx

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/62/build-an-mp3-player/

Hope they help!